# Closing -> Duplicate: no matches with number of results. Is it a bug?

Tags: bug, duplicate-questions, search, flag-dialog

I don't know if it is a bug or something else. When I type a question title, it has returned me **11 results** with the previous query. When I type more then no result is found, but **11 results** remain same.

[image]

Is it a bug or something else?

Comment: Looks to me that it keeps the entire list of results from the last successful auto-search.  Feature or bug, not sure.

Comment: What looks buggy to me is that you don't see the 11 results from the previous autosearch. I do.

Comment: @KevinB and I blame that to caching.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The results are cached from your previous search terms:

[image]

If I just type "migration gcm", I get 11 results, adding "to fc" produce 0 results, so the modal just keep the previous results around in case I'm just typing extra words.

Comment: Isn't this what the question already stated? But this doesn't really explain if it's a bug or not and will it be fixed.

Comment: @eis no, I'm explaining the mechanics of the modal and how is the behavior expected. Basically I'm saying that it is by design.

Comment: Then the bug would be the previous search results not hanging around for OP? Seems the difference between your screenshot and theirs is list persistence.

Comment: @CubeJockey I would blame that to OP that is a slow typer. I can reproduce the issue if I type slower.

Comment: Blame the OP for being a slow typer...? Wow, really? That's some serious [user blaming](http://www.kaylaheffernan.com/blog/2015/9/27/stop-blaming-your-users).

Comment: Also, I fail to see how this proves that behaviour OP sees is by design.